# EF 6 - Migrations não reflete alterações nas entidades

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2015, migrations

Alterei minhas entidades e rodei o comando `Update-Database -Verbose -Script` somente para ver em `SQL` quais alterações seriam realizadas. Gerou o script legal com todas as alterações.

Fechei a janela do script e rodei o `Add-Migration`, que não mapeou nenhuma das alterações que fiz nas entidades, aparentemente assumindo que eu apliquei as alterações no banco.

Não há nenhum `Migration` além dos antigos na minha pasta de `Migrations`, no entanto quando uso o comando `Get-Migrations` existe um `201706301953129_AutomaticMigration`, uma migração nova, que não está na árvore de arquivos, nem no diretório, nem em lugar nenhum no meu computador.

Gostaria muito de deletar esse arquivo porque creio que ele que fez as minhas mudanças serem ignoradas, mas não consegui descobrir como ainda. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? Tem algum comando para **Entity Framework 6** no **Package Manager Console** para deletar esse arquivo?

Comment: Essa foi a solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um -force para sua última migration antes de sua migration automática.